# InputDispatcher Error

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

```
INFO/ActivityManager(68): Process com.example (pid 390) has died.
ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '406ed580 com.example/com.example.afeTest (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '406ed580 com.example/com.example.afeTest (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=165, events=0x8
```

Can anyone tell what may be the reason behind this error?

I've ported a native code on the Android-ndk.
One thing I noticed regarding fd (that may be some reason :S)

My code uses fd_sets which was defined in winsock2.h
But I didn't find fd_sets defined in android-ndk.
So I had included "select.h" where fd_set is a typedef in the android-ndk:

```
typedef __kernel_fd_set   fd_set;
```

Here is the log cat:

```
04-06 11:15:32.405: INFO/DEBUG(31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-06 11:15:32.405: INFO/DEBUG(31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:2.3.3/GRI34/101070:eng/test-keys'
04-06 11:15:32.415: INFO/DEBUG(31): pid: 335, tid: 348  >>> com.example <<<
04-06 11:15:32.426: INFO/DEBUG(31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
04-06 11:15:32.426: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r0 deadbaad  r1 0000000c  r2 00000027  r3 00000000
04-06 11:15:32.445: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r4 00000080  r5 afd46668  r6 0000a000  r7 00000078
04-06 11:15:32.445: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r8 804ab00d  r9 002a9778  10 00100000  fp 00000001
04-06 11:15:32.445: INFO/DEBUG(31):  ip ffffffff  sp 44295d10  lr afd19375  pc afd15ef0  cpsr 00000030
04-06 11:15:32.756: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #00  pc 00015ef0  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:32.756: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #01  pc 00013852  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:32.767: INFO/DEBUG(31): code around pc:
04-06 11:15:32.785: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd15ed0 68241c23 d1fb2c00 68dae027 d0042a00 
04-06 11:15:32.785: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd15ee0 20014d18 6028447d 48174790 24802227 
04-06 11:15:32.785: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd15ef0 f7f57002 2106eb56 ec92f7f6 0563aa01 
04-06 11:15:32.796: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd15f00 60932100 91016051 1c112006 e818f7f6 
04-06 11:15:32.807: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd15f10 2200a905 f7f62002 f7f5e824 2106eb42 
04-06 11:15:32.815: INFO/DEBUG(31): code around lr:
04-06 11:15:32.815: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd19354 b0834a0d 589c447b 26009001 686768a5 
04-06 11:15:32.825: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd19364 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901 
04-06 11:15:32.836: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd19374 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee 
04-06 11:15:32.836: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd19384 bdf01c30 000281a8 ffffff88 1c0fb5f0 
04-06 11:15:32.846: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd19394 43551c3d a904b087 1c16ac01 604d9004 
04-06 11:15:32.856: INFO/DEBUG(31): stack:
04-06 11:15:32.856: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295cd0  00000408  
04-06 11:15:32.867: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295cd4  afd18407  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:32.875: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295cd8  afd4270c  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:32.875: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295cdc  afd426b8  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:32.885: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295ce0  00000000  
04-06 11:15:32.896: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295ce4  afd19375  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:32.896: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295ce8  804ab00d  /data/data/com.example/lib/libAFE.so
04-06 11:15:32.896: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295cec  afd183d9  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:32.906: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295cf0  00000078  
04-06 11:15:32.906: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295cf4  00000000  
04-06 11:15:32.906: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295cf8  afd46668  
04-06 11:15:32.906: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295cfc  0000a000  [heap]
04-06 11:15:32.916: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d00  00000078  
04-06 11:15:32.927: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d04  afd18677  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:32.927: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d08  df002777  
04-06 11:15:32.945: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d0c  e3a070ad  
04-06 11:15:32.945: INFO/DEBUG(31): #00 44295d10  002c43a0  [heap]
04-06 11:15:32.945: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d14  002a9900  [heap]
04-06 11:15:32.956: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d18  afd46608  
04-06 11:15:32.966: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d1c  afd11010  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:32.976: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d20  002c4298  [heap]
04-06 11:15:32.976: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d24  fffffbdf  
04-06 11:15:33.006: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d28  000000da  
04-06 11:15:33.006: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d2c  afd46450  
04-06 11:15:33.006: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d30  000001b4  
04-06 11:15:33.026: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d34  afd13857  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:33.026: INFO/DEBUG(31): #01 44295d38  afd46450  
04-06 11:15:33.035: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d3c  afd13857  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:33.056: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d40  804ab00d  /data/data/com.example/lib/libAFE.so
04-06 11:15:33.056: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d44  44295e8c  
04-06 11:15:33.056: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d48  804ab00d  /data/data/com.example/lib/libAFE.so
04-06 11:15:33.056: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d4c  804bfec3  /data/data/com.example/lib/libAFE.so
04-06 11:15:33.056: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d50  002c43a0  [heap]
04-06 11:15:33.066: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d54  44295e8c  
04-06 11:15:33.066: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d58  804ab00d  /data/data/com.example/lib/libAFE.so
04-06 11:15:33.076: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d5c  002a9778  [heap]
04-06 11:15:33.085: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d60  00000078  
04-06 11:15:33.085: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d64  afd14769  /system/lib/libc.so
04-06 11:15:33.085: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d68  44295e8c  
04-06 11:15:33.085: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d6c  805d9763  /data/data/com.example/lib/libAFE.so
04-06 11:15:33.085: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d70  44295e8c  
04-06 11:15:33.085: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d74  8051dc35  /data/data/com.example/lib/libAFE.so
04-06 11:15:33.085: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d78  0000003a  
04-06 11:15:33.085: INFO/DEBUG(31):     44295d7c  002a9900  [heap]
04-06 11:15:37.126: DEBUG/Zygote(33): Process 335 terminated by signal (11)
04-06 11:15:37.146: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Process com.example (pid 335) has died.
04-06 11:15:37.178: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '406f03a0 com.example/com.example.afeTest (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
04-06 11:15:37.178: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '406f03a0 com.example/com.example.afeTest (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-06 11:15:37.185: INFO/BootReceiver(68): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
04-06 11:15:37.576: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 266K, 47% free 4404K/8199K, external 3520K/3903K, paused 306ms
04-06 11:15:37.835: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 203K, 47% free 4457K/8391K, external 3520K/3903K, paused 120ms
04-06 11:15:37.886: INFO/WindowManager(68): WIN DEATH: Window{406f03a0 com.example/com.example.afeTest paused=false}
04-06 11:15:38.095: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 67K, 47% free 4518K/8391K, external 3511K/3903K, paused 94ms
04-06 11:15:38.095: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(68): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.575MB for 196628-byte allocation
04-06 11:15:38.126: DEBUG/dalvikvm(126): GC_EXPLICIT freed 110K, 51% free 2903K/5895K, external 4701K/5293K, paused 2443ms
04-06 11:15:38.217: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1K, 46% free 4708K/8647K, external 3511K/3903K, paused 96ms
04-06 11:15:38.225: INFO/WindowManager(68): WIN DEATH: Window{406f72f8 com.example/com.example.afeTest paused=false}
04-06 11:15:38.405: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 492K, 50% free 4345K/8647K, external 3511K/3903K, paused 96ms
04-06 11:15:38.485: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=164, events=0x8
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a memory leak that has been fixed later.
That was crashing the program.

Comment: How did you detect the memory leak?

Comment: How did know the memory leak and fix it?

Comment: How did you find the issue?

Comment: Debugging the AFE library.