# Nexus 5 denies running app installed via ADB

Tags: android, debugging, adb

When I install app from android studio or from command line, app is always starting in debug mode, even when phone not connected to computer. So I see dialog "waiting for debugger to attach" and app is not launching until I attach debugger. Is there ny way to disable this behaviour?

My phone is Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1
ADB version 1.0.32
Running on Windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560041/3433402

(I can't mark as duplicate because I don't have enough points.)

Comment: flagged it for you ;)