# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start this animator on a detached view

Tags: java, android

Hi in the I am impementing a search functionality it is giving me an error.Can not start this animator on an detached view .
Can any one help me how to reslove it
Logcat error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start this animator on a detached view!
        at android.view.RenderNode.addAnimator(RenderNode.java:824)
        at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget(RenderNodeAnimator.java:295)
        at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget(RenderNodeAnimator.java:280)
        at android.animation.RevealAnimator.<init>(RevealAnimator.java:37)
        at android.view.ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(ViewAnimationUtils.java:71)
        at com.shahroz.svlibrary.widgets.MaterialSearchView.display(MaterialSearchView.java:219)
```

java:

```
public void display() {
        if (isSearchViewVisible()) return;
        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mOnSearchListener.searchViewOpened();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            final Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(cardLayout,
                    cardLayout.getWidth() - Util.dpToPx(getContext(), 56),
                    Util.dpToPx(getContext(), 23),
                    0,
                    (float) Math.hypot(cardLayout.getWidth(), cardLayout.getHeight()));//error at this line
            animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    searchLayout.setVis
```

Comment: possible duplicate to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819429/cannot-start-this-animator-on-a-detached-view-reveal-effect ?

Comment: @mangkool I tried it is not working