# Notification channel unrecoverably broken (only some devices)

Tags: android, notifications, channel, battery, huawei-mobile-services

I have an app that reminds the user with a notification every day to enter data.

I have two decives I test this app on, both running with Android 8.00, API 26 as shown in Android Studio:

- **Huawei P10** (bought in Germany)
- **Huawei P10 Mate** (bought in China)

When I test the app with my **P10** or an emulator all is working fine. The Notification appears at given time even when the app is not running in the background anymore.

However, when I try the app with my **P10 Mate** the Notification only appears as long as the app is running in the background. When I remove the app from recent tasks the notification disappears from the status bar and no new notifications are being made.

When looking at the logcat of Android Studio for the **P10 Mate** I noticed that I get the following error:

[image: Channel Error]

I have read about some devices using aggresive power saving methods resulting in notifications not comming through. I tried to changing some settings but the error still persists.

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I haven't encountered this error before but it seems like it could be several other reasons in other parts of your code. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459719/why-i-am-getting-error-channel-is-unrecoverably-broken-and-will-be-disposed